# Strange behavior in rigging method

Tags: rigging

When linking a bone as a pole target, the arm twists. Then I can straighten it, but when the two bones are linked, the first thing that happens is that it becomes deformed.

Is this the normal behavior?

[image]

[image]

[In the screen recording it looks clearer than in the screenshots (YouTube)](https://youtu.be/P3fYFzASIQU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because it doesn't know how to orientate the IK bone, change the *Pole Angle* in the IK constraint to something like 90 or -90°:

[image]